# MKMapView showing up off center

Tags: ios, xcode, mkmapview

Could anyone please explain to me why my view is showing up off center:

[image]

When quite clearly I've defined it like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you add AutoLayout to the MKMapView?
Just add top, bottom, left, right constraints to the superview with 0 value.

Answer (score 0):

That's Right , You must select the pin option

[see Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3lwA.png)

and add the constraints by selecting the red lines for bottom, left, top and right.

[see Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zKR6.png)